# The biggest exponent that can be computed

Tags: big-numbers, system-limitations

I am struggling with my crypt assignments and constantly getting overflow errors.
Below is a simplified version of the problems I am experiencing

```
In[5]:= a:= 44^65537

In[6]:= b:= 22^65537

In[7]:= GCD[a,b]
```

> ```
> Out[7]= 2265.....312 very big number
> ```

However I want to get an exponent with up to 13 digits or 48 bits to be exact.

If I do

```
In[8]:= a:= 44^6553700000000

In[9]:= b:= 22^6553700000000

In[10]:= GCD[a,b]
```

> General::ovfl: Overflow occurred in computation.
>
> General::ovfl: Overflow occurred in computation.
>
> GCD::exact: Argument Overflow[] in GCD[Overflow[], Overflow[]] is not an exact number.
>
> Out[10]= GCD[Overflow[], Overflow[]]

And now those question pop into my head

- The numbers becomes so big that the RAM can't handle it ?
- There is limit for the exponential power in *Mathematica* ?
- There is limit in my OS ?
- Numbers so big are impossible to calculate ?

Any input is appreciated !

Comment: OScam - you should learn the difference between `:=` and `=` in Mathematica - have a look here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/18487#18487

Comment: 2^48 bits is 2^(48) / 8 = 2^45 bytes. That comes to 32 terabytes, at least using the 2^10=1K convention. So yeah, you may be up against limitations imposed by RAM, Mathematica and OS.

Comment: Thank you for making my question clean and nice, thanks for pointing out difference := and = i didn't knew about difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first port of call should be to have a look at the documentation for [`$MaxNumber`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$MaxNumber.html), which says:

> `$MaxNumber` gives the maximum arbitrary‐precision number that can be
>   represented on a particular computer system.

On my machine, `$MaxNumber` returns $1.605216761933662 \times 10^{1355718576299609}$.

With regards to your number, $44^{6553700000000}$, I initially had to use [this online calculator](http://www.ttmath.org/online_calculator) to convert it, it's approximately $3.36*10^{10770695805887}$. So, we need to compare the exponents, which initially seems fine.

```
10770695805887 > 1355718576299609
(* False *)
```

However, actually calculating this number *exactly* takes a very long time... as pointed out by [Daniel Lichtblau](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/51/daniel-lichtblau) it is likely a memory limitation!

Changing to machine-precision works fine though, since that is 53 bits...look at [Control the Precision and Accuracy of Numerical Results](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/ControlThePrecisionAndAccuracyOfNumericalResults.html), but unfortunately that won't work with `GCD[a, b]` as machine-precision numbers are not exact.

```
44.^6553700000000
(* 3.3617443923642*10^10770695805887 *)
```

Comment: Sorry, I messed up the edit :D

Comment: No long-term harm done :-)

Comment: 20686623745
Out[1]= 2.174188391646043 10

Comment: i am using mac book pro windows 8.1 

maxnumber shows me:

        20686623745
Out[1]= 2.174188391646043 10

Does This power 20686623745 mean my PC can calculate upto this number ?

if i use better Machine with more ram , problem can solve ?

apologize for asking too much i am total noob :(

Comment: Yes, if that's what it returns then that's the largest number Mathematica can achieve. Using a better machine won't necessarily solve your problem - calculating $44^{6553700000000}$ exactly might well be beyond the capability of Mathematica.

Answer (score 2):

This works fine for me (v.10.0.0 on Mac Pro):

```
Clear[a, b]
a = 44^(65537);
b = 22^(65537);
c = GCD[a, b];
```

Where all the digits of c are computed and revealed within about 2 seconds.

```
N@c
```

2.265859854928417*10^87978

Comment: Same here.  Finished instantly. `$Version == "10.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 4, 2014)"`

Comment: This doesn't answer the question? The problem was with larger exponents...

Answer (score 2):

Many times you can solve this kind of problems using realtions such as

```
GCD[a,b]=GCD[b,Mod[a,b]]
```

and substituting conventional functions for modular ones more specialized.

For example, instead of

```
Mod[x^y,z]
```

you have to use

```
PowerMod[x,y,z]
```

that works if z is not too big, even if x^y is huge.

Coming back to your example and using different formulas

```
 In[8]:= a:= 44^6553700000000

 In[9]:= b:= 22^6553700000000

 In[10]:= GCD[a,b]
```

You want to calculate

```
 GCD[(2*m)^x,m^x]
```

I would take this formula (you can find it on the Wikipedia)

gcd(a + m·b, b) = gcd(a, b)

And for you

```
 GCD[44^6553700000000, 22^6553700000000] = 
 GCD[(2*22)^6553700000000, 22^6553700000000] =
 GCD[(2^6553700000000)*(22^6553700000000), 22^6553700000000] =
 GCD[0,22^6553700000000]=22^6553700000000
```

You can check it with smaller numbers.

Though I know Mathematica should do it by its own means.